# GAE Channel API - 400 Bad Request on disconnect

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a chat application using GAE's Channel API in Python.

I don't think I've set it up correctly. When I leave a page I get the following error message in my browser console:

http://localhost:8080/_ah/channel/dev?command=disconnect&channel=0e0acee3bd…122e0acaa86eeb-channel-1354440420-1452408747-mike|5066549580791808&client=1 400 (Bad Request)

Also, when I send chat message it sends duplicate messages, so I'm guessing users are not being properly disconnected.

I've set it up such that when user visits page, my backend code checks if they are logged in, and if so will automatically create token based on their username and the permalink ID of the page.

I then create a token, calling channel.create_channel method and pass that token as a value in the dict I include when I render my template (Jinja).

In my front-end I open the channel with the token. My on-close function is:

```
socket.onclose = function(){
   connected = false;
}
```

In my app.yaml file I have included inbound_services: - channel presence.

In my backend code, I have '/_ah/channel/disconnected/'routed to a class that gets that permalink's entity instance, finds the client id from a list of connections and removes that connection from the entity.

Can you someone help me think about the Channel API the right way?

Comment: here's a basic demo I wrote, it might help: https://github.com/PaulCollingwood/channelapidemo don't worry about the message when you leave the channel, unless you are catching those messages on the server side also, they just are there to tell you the user has disconnected, if you ignore them it'll still work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain to me how clients are disconnected from the channel?

I was under the impression this had to be done manually. For instance, I enabled "inbound_services: -channel presence".

Comment: I route '/_ah/channel/disconnected/' to a class in my python code that gets the channel of the user and removes it from the datastore. (My entity has a StructuredProperty that keeps track of all connections).

Comment: clients will disconnect by closing the page or the channel times out. Or I guess you can close it on the server side but offhand I can't recall. What's your question? That you get an error? Do you see the disconnect handler call/request on the server logs?

Comment: Isn't it necessary to actually keep a list of active connections on the server side? How would I know which channels to push a new message to? Therefore I thought it was necessary to  actually route '/_ah/channel/disconnected/' to a class that finds the channel that closed and remove it from the list of active connections.

Comment: I think I've singled out the problem. It seems whenever I leave a page and immediately return to it or refresh a page, the channel is not being closed properly and I'm getting duplicate channels with the same channel ID. I'm building a chat application and this basically means that duplicate messages are being sent to the client with the channel ID. Any help on this issue? much appreciated

Comment: I'd just stick with creating a new channel when a page is left and returned to. Then you have one channel per user, and it's always up to date. You can't re-use channels for different users (well, you can but you won't have a good time as I think you are seeing).

Comment: I don't understand. Can you confirm it is necessary to keep a list of active connections in the datastore? If I have 10 users on a page with chat box, I need to store the 10 channel ID's so I can send out a new message to all 10 channels correct?

Comment: If you look at google's example, you'll see this:     channel.send_message(self.game.userX.user_id() + self.game.key().name(),
message) - you can just "name" the user and the channel will work the rest out. So you don't need to store the token necessarily (if that's what you call the channel ID). But yes, you'll have to track what users are connected to know to send them messages, yes!